# Showing the parsed json data in html/Text format in ios tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uitableview

Thanks,

I get json data from server.
I want to show the data on table view Cell based on user choice.

if choice is "TEXT"
the table view Cell will show simple numeric/text content as it is.

if choice is "HTML"
the table view Cell will show charts or web view type content(including bars representing data in json).

What is the best approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Create two separate UITableViewCell subclasses for each and then switch between them as the user toggles.

Answer (score 0):

u need to create two types of views (UIView and UIWebView probably) and display them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. on "TEXT" I am adding matrix view to table cell showing all the data. on "HTML" I am supposed to show same matrix. but the value are shown in graphical format.